# Extracting multiple keywords and assigning to a new column

Tags: python

**Overview**

I have the following code that extract terms from a large string in the 'Jobtitle' column and assigns the specified word - in this case 'engineer', 'scientist', 'analyst' to a new column called 'job_cat'

**Problem**

Currently each subsequent line of code overwrites the line above e.g. only the line 'analyst' applies and all other values in the 'Jobtitle' column are 'other' even ones that are supposed to be 'engineer' or 'scientist'.

How do I structure the code so that all 3 values are extracted into the new column 'Jobtitle'?

```
glassdoor['job_cat'] = np.where(glassdoor['Jobtitle'].str.contains('engineer'), 'engineer', 'other') 
glassdoor['job_cat'] = np.where(glassdoor['Jobtitle'].str.contains('scientist'), 'scientist', 'other') 
glassdoor['job_cat'] = np.where(glassdoor['Jobtitle'].str.contains('analyst'), 'analyst', 'other')
```

Comment: There might be another way to approach this.  Can you please post (update the question) with a sample from your dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Option 1: Elegant Solution Using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)***

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'jobtitle': ['job scientist', 'job is engineer', 'job analyst', 'hey nothing']}

glassdoor = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Find and replace those meeting jobs key words
for job_option in ['engineer', 'analyst', 'scientist']:
    glassdoor.loc[(glassdoor['jobtitle'].str.contains(job_option), 'job_cat')] = job_option
# Fill NaN with other
glassdoor['job_cat'] = glassdoor['job_cat'].fillna("other")

# Print the output.
print(glassdoor)
```

Output:

```
          jobtitle    job_cat
0    job scientist  scientist
1  job is engineer   engineer
2      job analyst    analyst
3      hey nothing      other
```

***Option 2 : Use `np.where` Multiple times***

```
glassdoor['job_cat'] = np.where(glassdoor['Jobtitle'].str.contains('analyst'), 'analyst', np.where(glassdoor['Jobtitle'].str.contains('scientist'), 'scientist', np.where(glassdoor['Jobtitle'].str.contains('engineer'), 'engineer', 'other')))
```

Answer (score 3):

I see you're using **Pandas str function**.

- You can use `extract` function instead of contains. This gets all your matches at once.
- For values which don't have any, you can use `fillna` to insert **other**.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
         ['im scientist', 'im engineer', 'im analyst', 'nothing'], 
         columns=['jobtitle']
     )

df['job_cat'] = df['jobtitle'].str.extract("(scientist|engineer|analyst)")
df['job_cat'] = df['job_cat'].fillna("other")
```

Output:

```
            jobtitle    job_cat
0   i am a scientist  scientist
1   this is engineer   engineer
2  hey im an analyst    analyst
3        hey nothing      other
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you need to **nest** the `np.where` otherwise anything which does not match "engineer" will be referred to as "other" (including "analyst"), same for 2nd and last line, which will mess your output.

You could use **nested np.where** rather, as mentioned by @AvivYaniv. But if you got many different categories for this column or you would want to do further processing, may I suggest you to use `apply` for a far-more human readable approach.

Step1: define your function to operate on each val of the concerned column and return the value you want.

Step2: apply on the desired column and assign the values back to a new column.

```
def extract_job_title(val):
    if val.contains("engineer"):
        return "engineer"
    if val.contains("scientist"):
        return "scientist"
    if val.contains("analyst"):
        return "analyst"
    return "other"


glassdoor['job_cat']  = glassdoor.Jobtitle.apply(extract_job_title)
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'Jobtitle': 'I am scientist'},{'Jobtitle': 'I am no one'}])


def job_cat(x):
    if 'engineer' in x:
      return 'engineer'
    elif 'scientist' in x:
      return 'scientist'
    elif 'analyst' in x:
      return 'analyst'
    else:
      return 'other'


df['job_cat'] = df['Jobtitle'].apply(job_cat)

print(df)
```

output

```
         Jobtitle    job_cat
0  I am scientist  scientist
1     I am no one      other
```